# Jhipster app can not login within an iframe

Tags: spring, spring-security, jhipster

My application which is created in jHipster and resides in an iFrame,

However I get an

> unauthorized

page whenever i want to login.

i already tried disabling CSRF , but i am not able to login, it works fine when it is not in an iframe,

Please help

thanks
A

Comment: By default, Spring Security adds the `X-Frame-Options: DENY` header which denies any attempt to render a page inside an iframe. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/headers.html#headers-frame-options

Comment: Hello, I allowed xframe, and also disabled xss protection, I am still getting unauthorised on login, pl let me know what protection more I need to disable

Comment: Have you looked at browser's console to see if there are Content Security Policy errors? Or is there an error in the server logs?

Comment: Is it something to do with Basic Authetication, my current application is in Basic auth, if i create a dummy new app with JWT it works. what is the solution you think?